# How to handle list threshold 5000 for filtered items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, list-view-threshold

Its SharePoint online. We have indexed all the column which are being used to filter/query.

A total number of items in the list are around 100 thousand.

Filter works perfectly fine. e.g. if we search/filter with the title that contains W, it works fine and returns around 400 records out of 100 thousand.

the challenge is , if the filter is "Title contains a" then it returns around 12k items and gives standard threshold exceeded error.

is there any way to handle this. AFAIK indexing was the only option.

I had read somewhere this limit is going to be increased from 5000 for SharePoint online? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is news about upcoming SharePoint 2016 on-prem will have > 5000 limit but don't know so far, As RTM version will generally available during the 1st week of May 2016. I am not sure, if that apply to Office 365 as well or not?

Below office blog pointed out all the possible solution:

[Manage large lists and libraries in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-B4038448-EC0E-49B7-B853-679D3D8FB784)

Answer (score 0):

SP2016 still will have the 5k limit. The only thing that will change is that [Sharepoint will be crating indexes automatically](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2015/08/27/navigating-list-view-thresholds-in-sharepoint-server-2016-it-preview/) in your case it will not help as you already have them in place. For large amount of data in list library I always drop standard list views and switch to custom search. Map the fields you need to filter to managed properties and and then use search. Search uses its index rather than query list therefore you circumnavigate issue completely. With more effort you could create a web part that very closely resembles standard view so users would not notice much difference.